# Why my C# Code Checker method always returns true?

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a program, that checks if a given **.txt file**, containing a **C# code**, has **valid brackets**.

When i paste a simple code like this:

```
if(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

My program says it is valid, which is true. But if i remove a bracket, like this:

```
if(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

It still says it's valid.

**Here is my method for checking brackets:**

```
static void CheckBrackets()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Write("You file name (Default path is .....\\netcoreapp2.1\\): ");

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();

            Stack openingBrackets = new Stack();
            Queue closingBrackets = new Queue();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
            {
                bool check = true;
                string str = reader.ReadToEnd();
                char[] code = str.ToCharArray();

                foreach (char ch in code)
                {
                    if(ch == '(' || ch == '[' || ch == '{')
                    {
                        openingBrackets.Push(ch);
                    }
                    else if(ch == ')' || ch == ']' || ch == '}')
                    {
                        closingBrackets.Enqueue(ch);
                    }
                }

                while (openingBrackets.Count == 0 && closingBrackets.Count == 0)
                {
                    char currentOpeningBracket = (char)openingBrackets.Pop();
                    char currentClosingBracket = (char)closingBrackets.Dequeue();

                    if ((currentOpeningBracket == '(' && currentClosingBracket != ')')
                     || (currentOpeningBracket == '[' && currentClosingBracket != ']')
                     || (currentOpeningBracket == '{' && currentClosingBracket != '}'))
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }
                }

                if(check == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Valid.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Not valid.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: `while (openingBrackets.Count == 0 && closingBrackets.Count == 0)` -- that's almost certainly wrong. Loop while both of the queues are empty?

Comment: where in your code example isn't present close bracket?

Comment: Your `while` condition is true only if there is no brackets in the code. So if there are any (even mismatched) the code inside will not get executed.

Comment: Did you try debugging? This would have been easy to debug, it's a very small program, you can step through it in 30 seconds.

Comment: You should probably check that you have the same number of opening and closing brackets before you both comparing them individually too. If one collection has 1 and the other 2 then you know they are not going to match without needing to look at each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify the `while` section of your code with this:

```
if (openingBrackets.Count != closingBrackets.Count)
{
    check = false;
}
else
{
    while (openingBrackets.Count > 0 && closingBrackets.Count > 0)
    {
        char currentOpeningBracket = (char)openingBrackets.Pop();
        char currentClosingBracket = (char)closingBrackets.Dequeue();

        if ((currentOpeningBracket == '(' && currentClosingBracket != ')')
        || (currentOpeningBracket == '[' && currentClosingBracket != ']')
        || (currentOpeningBracket == '{' && currentClosingBracket != '}'))
        {
            check = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in other words - while `Count` of stack and queue not equal 0, do...

Comment: @Chris, true... but it's more to OP... and it's kinda different issue, that, probably, needs different question on stackowerflow

Comment: Thanks! This was one of the issues. However, the main issue was that the poped element was never the opposite bracket of the dequeued element. I fixed this issue by removing the whole while and when the program faces a closing bracket, it instantly checks if peeking the stack returns the opposite bracket. 

Thanks for the help!